# How to import/export components in react project running on react cdn link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have done few projects in react, but by using create-react-app. I am trying to do the same but only with react cdn. I put every component in there separate .js file. But I am having difficulty in connecting those components to the main App.js component. It seem like react not recognising  is a component in App.js. Thanks

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="./App.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import Header from './Component/Header.js'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <div>
             <Header />
             <h2>Hi, I am a Main!</h2>;
          </div>
      ) 
    }
}
```

Header.js

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <h2>Hi, I am a Header!</h2>;
    }
  }

export default Header
```

Comment: Open the console. Read the error messages.

Comment: "I am trying to do the same but only with react cdn." — I really wouldn't. It's inefficient and doesn't let you use all the useful tools that npm and webpack give you.

Answer (score 0):

Importing Header.js in App.js won't work. Instead, you import all the javascript files that you are using in the HTML file only then it would work.

in the HTML file.